# problema con modal bootstrap 4 y OverlayScrollbar (body)

Tags: javascript, laravel, modal, plugin, scrollbar

estoy utilizando el plugin Overlayscrollbar de kingsora en mi body, y al utilizarlo funciona todo bien, pero causa un problema en los modal

Intente cambiando el `z-index: 1;` a `z-index: auto !important;` del css Overlayscrollbar, pero no pasa nada.

este es el script que utilizo

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
OverlayScrollbars(document.querySelectorAll("body"), { 
  className : "os-theme-dark",
  resize    : "both",
  scrollbars : {
    visibility       : "auto",
    autoHide         : "move",
    autoHideDelay    : 800,
    dragScrolling    : true,
    clickScrolling   : false,
    touchSupport     : true,
    snapHandle       : false
  }
});});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"><link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/overlayscrollbars/1.8.0/css/OverlayScrollbars.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/overlayscrollbars/1.8.0/js/jquery.overlayScrollbars.js"></script> <html> <body> Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo Ejemplo <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#flipFlop"> Modal </button> <!-- The modal --> <div class="modal fade" id="flipFlop" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> <div class="modal-dialog" role="document"> <div class="modal-content"> <div class="modal-header"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button> <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">Default modal</h4> </div> <div class="modal-body"> One fine body... </div> <div class="modal-footer"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> </div> </div> </div> </div> </body> </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu `#flipFlop.modal` está dentro de `.os-padding` y dicho elemento tiene un `z-index: 1`, por eso tu modal aparece por detrás del backdrop. Asignarle un `z-index` mayor al modal no hace nada porque nunca va a aparecer por delante del elemento padre.

Lo que te conviene hacer esa sacar el código del modal y ponerlo por fuera de `.os-padding`, sino le vas a tener que sacar el `z-index` al elemento y no se que consecuencias puede traer con el resto del funcionamiento.

Como regla general, siempre te conviene poner el modal lo más arriba del DOM posible.

Comment: De echo le quite el z-index del css al plugin y funciono correctamente! 
Muchas Gracias!!